# Need a INT from Eloquent. Getting JSON string

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this query:

```
 static function findIdOnName($pageName){
    return Fanpages::select('id')
                ->where('url', '=', $pageName)
            ->get();
}
```

Response: (when done print_r)

> [{"id":17}]

I just want the INT (in this case 17) I searched the interwebs for it, but I can't find anthing about it. Randomly tried adding ->toString() etc to the query, but so far, no good.

Comment: If the response is json, then start by json_decoding it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code returns a `Collection` with a single `Model` (or multiple models if there are more matching the where clause), while the method you need is `pluck`:

```
return Fanpages::where('url', '=', $pageName)->pluck('id');
// returns INT 17
```

as it returns value for column `id` of the first row matching `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not return a view with data, then Laravel will automatically convert your data into json. In order to accomplish what you want you can simply do something like

```
$data = Fanpages::select('id')->where('url', '=', $pageName)->get();
die($data->id);
```

However, exiting the application like this isn't recommended. You should either keep the json response and work with that, or send the data to a basic blade template.

Comment: Beat me to it. :) This is the correct answer, have an upvote.

Comment: Chris, its not to show in a view, I now display it in a view just to show what it returns. I eventually could do: return $data->id;

Comment: @Chilion could you edit your question to post more of your code? I'm not really sure what the problem is. I'd be happy to update my answer.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your answer. I was looking for really getting an INT in return, so the answer of Deczo is exactly what I was needing. Guess my questionskills could use a little update! :)